# Angular 2 /Ionic 2 undefined property causes template to not refresh

Tags: angular, ionic2

I just got done trying to fix the below issue for 4 hours.

```
<ion-card *ngIf="user">
      <ion-item>
        <h2>{{user.FirstName}}!</h2>
        <p>{{user.Company.Name}}</p>
      </ion-item>
 </ion-card>
 <some-other-component></some-other-component>


user = {
    FirstName: 'Nick'
};
```

Notice that `user.Company` is not set.  My entire component just stopped working.  Not just the `ion-card`,  `some-other-component` rendered once and then stopped updating.  It was responding to click events, but never updating.

My Question is:  is there any way to force Angular / Ionic to display that it failed to render versus just failing?

My fix was to:  `<p>{{user?.Company?.Name}}</p>`  it's scary to me that we are now going to have to check every object for property existence.  I'm wondering if there is something I just need to set/configure in order to change how this behaves.  Desired outcome is either a console error, or to just render like Angular 1.x did.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no setting to force the rendering on runtime errors. You have to check the assignment with '?' or bind to a method that checks internal the assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Just one elvis operator (?) is needed in this case. Since you're including `*ngIf="user"` in the `ion-card` element, you just need to check if the `Company` property is not null like this:

```
<p>{{user.Company?.Name}}</p>
```

Comment: Regardless of my solve the point is i dont want to have to do this for every piece of data that might be null.  The question is how can i get angular to either error out loudly, or make it ignore nulls.

Comment: @Nix i agree with sebaferreras answer if you have null for company array or data int he company array then in the .ts file you have to use for condition and push null value to localy created array in the success callback of you post or get API calls.

Comment: You know how unrealistic this is in a real world data model?   As stated in my question I'm looking for something other than `elvis`.